# Correctly managing context in Ruby mixins

Tags: ruby

There must be something simple here, but I'm missing it.

I have a module called Genotyping, with a class called Genotype:

```
module Genotyping

  class Genotype
```

And I have a unit testing class where I'm trying to do some work with the module:

```
require "test/unit"
require "../genotyping.rb"

include Genotyping

class TestGenotyping < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_genotype
    geno = Genotyping::Genotype.new
```

And what I get when running the unit test file is:

```
  2) Error:
test_genotype(TestGenotyping):
NameError: uninitialized constant Genotyping::Genotype
```

If I remove the Genotyping:: qualifer, naturally enough I get:

```
      1) Error:
test_breeding_scenario(TestGenotyping):
NameError: uninitialized constant TestGenotyping::Genotype
```

I've taken a hard look around, and can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Problem not reproducible here (ruby 1.9.3p392). The 2nd `require` suggests you are using 1.8.x.

Comment: Also, not reproducible with 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Found it. One of the module classes was not properly closed, leading to all sorts of problems with scope.

Basically a typo, though hard to spot. Thanks, all.